# Pack display: inline-block divs

Tags: html, css

I have a number of `display: inline-block` div elements of fixed width and variable height.

I want to print each div without wasting paper. I concatenated the divs to make a single HTML document which I would then print. Example document with empty divs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test page</title>
<style type="text/css">
div{
display:inline-block;
width: 13cm;
background-color: #999;
margin: 1mm;
}
</style>

<div style="height:10cm"></div>
<div style="height:20cm"></div>
<div style="height:14cm"></div>
<div style="height:20cm"></div>
<div style="height:15cm"></div>
<div style="height:30cm"></div>
<div style="height:20cm"></div>
<div style="height:27cm"></div>
```

The result was unsatisfying. Firefox aligned the divs in a kind of table with each div taking up the bottom part of a "cell". This wastes a lot of space if I have a big div on the same "row" as a smaller one. I've also tried adding `float: left` to the div styling, but this only made the divs take up the top part of the "cells" instead of the bottom part.

What's the least kludgy way to fix this?

Comment: Are you looking for [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)?

Comment: Do you want [Pinterst](http://pinterest.com/jeyraof/taeyeon/) Style?

Comment: @cimmanon: That looks useful! Clarkson: Yes, that is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of your elements have the same width, you could use the `columns` property.  However, the elements will be arranged from top to bottom rather than left to right:

http://tinker.io/f834a

```
body { /* or whatever is containing your elements */
    columns: 13cm; /* width of your elements */
}
```

Prefixes may be necessary.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: After adding the -moz prefix, everything worked perfectly. This is probably the best solution as it doesn't even require javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, it works great if you're fine with just 2 columns:

```
div:nth-child(odd)
{
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

div:nth-child(even)
{
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rgx8r/)

Comment: I don't want each div on its own line, since that would be very wasteful.

Comment: Then why do you set `div`'s to be `30cm` high if you don't want them to be wasting space? Are you aware of [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) and `@media print`? You could just get rid of the heights using a print media query.

Comment: The divs will never appear anywhere else than on a piece of paper. I set them to be 30cm high as an example. The height is actually determined by the div contents, only the width is fixed.

Comment: Ah I get it now, in that case, I've updated the answer with the best I can come up with. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/Rgx8r/

Comment: Your new solution divides the divs into two columns, but if the div width is 13 and the page width is 42 (landscape A3 paper), three columns would be better. CSS multi-column is the solution.